# Weird admin-ajax.php problem

Tags: ajax, wp-admin

In my site, each request on the home page is also making a POST to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

> 10.30.4.122 - - [21/Aug/2015:06:07:53 -0400] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 275 "http://www.gktoday.in/"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"

I know its not normal, wp-admin/admin-ajax.php should only be coming from the websites backend or wp-admin, not the homepage. However, I am unable to judge what is causing this issue.
Please help.

Comment: Might be a plugin which do the call. Look at the `action` request parameter of this POST request to get a tip on what you have looking for.

Comment: `I know its not normal, wp-admin/admin-ajax.php should only be coming from the websites backend or wp-admin` <- No, it is normal to use admin-ajax.php for frontend AJAX requests.

Comment: I see a lots of processes. also, 122.168.248.244 - - [21/Aug/2015:07:24:06 -0400] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 275 "http://www.gktoday.in/list-of-committees-related-to-banking-finance-in-india/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"